# Wix: Assigning a property a value from a dialogue control

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Could someone please show me a simple example of assigning a value to a property that was supplied by a user from a dialogue edit control.

Comment: This link could help (http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Control Id="ServiceName" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="73" Width="200" Height="18" Property="SERVICENAME"></Control>
```

You can get value of the property like:  Value=[SERVICENAME].

Answer (score -1):

Look at WiX Tutorial article: [New Link in a Chain](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain), it explains how to add user registration page.

[User Interface Revised](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited) section contains other examples on how you can customize UI with WiX.